# How to use PS4 controller on PC?

Tags: controllers

I tried using DS4 windows but it does not work. Whenever I connect the controller using DS4 it registers 2 players and buttons stop working properly

Comment: I assume you're talking about "*DS4 Windows*", because DS4 (DualShock 4) is the name of the PS4 controller. Have you tried playing those games without DS4 Windows? If the game has also been released on PS4, there's a very high chance you don't need DS4 Windows at all (and maybe that's the reason why the game is seeing 2 controllers).

Comment: @Nolonar Yes I meant DS4 windows. I have tried playing FIFA , black ops 3 etc but i face the same problem in each of them

Comment: Like I said, have you tried playing those games without DS4 Windows?

Comment: I've used the PS4 controller for several games but never had to use  DS4 windows. They were all on Steam, and I've read somewhere that Steam does its own magic. But I use the controller with the USB cable attached, not Bluetooth.

Comment: I changed some settings and now it seems to working. Thanks everyone